# A cheap LNB for Blockstream satellite?

Tags: blockstream

Has anyone here built their own setup for connecting with the Blockstream satellite network?

I'm still looking for a cheap low-noise block downconverter.

> PLL LNB (linear polarization) w/ < = 200kHz LO stability

The ones I can find range from $100 -> $200..

Seems like 200kHz is not required, broader ranges are acceptable.
"L.O. Accuracy & Stability Within +/-1.5MHz" seems to do the trick and they are considerably cheaper (~15$).

Comment: I heard that Blockstream is going to sell a 100$ one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grubles has written up a guide for how to set up a blockstream satellite node: https://medium.com/@notgrubles/building-your-own-bitcoin-satellite-node-6061d3c93e7. That should be helpful; it includes links to amazon where you can buy all of the materials required.

Comment: The LNB that he uses has a LO stability range, I quote "L.O. Accuracy & Stability Within +/-1.5MHz ". I'm glad it works with a broader range.